# How did Fourier determine the coefficients of Fourier series?

Tags: mathematics, calculus, real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier

I was reading a chapter of Fourier's seminal work "Analytic Theory of Heat". The third chapter of this book was translated by the famous Stephen Hawking in his book "God created the integers". I fail to find a reference for how Fourier determine the coefficients of the Fourier series. Fourier, in my opinion, should be ranked as one the greatest mathematicians in the 19th century for he laid a great foundation on the development of trigonometric series, an essential area of modern mathematics.

Can you summarize his findings and point out which part of his work contains his derivation? I am greatly interested in how he was able to determine the coefficients of Fourier series, a task that Daniel Bernoulli failed to achieve.

I hope my shallow knowledge of mathematics do not offend and repel you from this question.

Comment: First of all, Fourier's book, Analytic theory of heat is freely available online in English translation: https://www3.nd.edu/~powers/ame.20231/fourier1878.pdf (and also in the original), so you can easily look yourself. Second, he determined Fourier coefficients in exactly the same way that modern undergraduate students do.

Comment: But which part of the book is relevant? Can you give me a reference? It is a thick book. If you know which chapter I can find, that would be highly valuable.

Comment: The book has a table of contents, by the way. Discussion of Fourier series is in Chap III, sections IV - VI. The formula for Fourier coefficients is written for the first time on p 185, formula D.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, don't know how to express my gratitude to your help. Thanks!

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko: Third, I very seriously doubt that Hawking did the translation.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Yeah, I had a chance to compare the two translations last night, they are identical. He just took the translation of someone else and put in his book. The advantage is that the format is clearer and friendlier to printing.